# Which is correct, “their life” or “their lives”?

Tags: phrase-usage, singular-vs-plural

Could someone here point out which of the 2 sentences below is grammatically correct?

1. "No one will know until the end of their earthly **life**."
2. "No one will know until the end of their earthly **lives**."

:s thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: **One** person doesn't have multiple lives, do they?

Comment: Without context, "their" refers to "no one" which is singular, the choose 1. However,in the text preceding the sentence, there may be a group of people with "lives", then 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it as meaning

> No one will know until the end of **that person’s** earthly life

which shows that it’s the singular *life* that’s called for.

Your question is a good one because the sentence’s subject, *no one*, is singular, but “officially,” *their* is plural.

English has no completely established possessive for 3rd-person singular and indeterminate geder. A century ago, style guides would have advised you to use *the end of **his** earthly life*, arguing that the grammatical masculine refers not just to males, but also to people of unspecified gender. But that’s [prescriptivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription), and today seen as exclusionary. And anyway, in reality, the way real people really speak, *their* is very, very often used as singular and by nearly everyone. One can see it as parallel to *you*, which of course today is used as both plural and singular.